# Modules not found in electron app after build on mac

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I am on a small electron app right now that uses vue and typescript. When i run the app in dev mode, everything works fine, but when I build the app with electron builder some modules get lost somehow. In my case the modules `adm-zip` and `sudo-prompt` somehow vanish during the build. So when the app starts, i get an error on this lines `const AdmZip = window.require('adm-zip');` I already tried to switch out the moduls with different ones, but that does not seem to matter. I guess it is a problem with webpack and typescript, but as I am not much of a webpack/electron guy, I surely miss something here. Other modules are working, like all the node stuff or the `electron-store` module that I am also using.

Is this a common problem and do i have to import the modules differently somehow? `Import` or the normal `require` do not work, I always have to do the `window.require`

This would be the repo:
https://github.com/w3champions/w3champions-launcher on branch AddLauncherStuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the problem: `adm-zip` has native dependencies and therefore you have to add it as a external dependency in the `vue.config.js` This should also work for other modules aswell, if they have depenant modules. I added the the following `vue.config.js` with `adm-zip` in the top folder of my project and now it gets baked into the built version. You do not have to add the `vue.config.js` to any build steps or anything, just adding it on the top of your project is good enough for webpack to pick it up.

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: ['adm-zip']
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have a reference to a sqlite library and had been trying everything to get the app running in production, in the end this was the missing step for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I executed "**npm run build**" with Admin privileges in Windows OS. Everything worked fine in my Windows.

I hope this article will help you.

https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/

Comment: I am on a mac and I accidentaly fixed the build when i removed the import and commented out some code. Current version is now not working anymore as described :/ I am also using electron-builder, not the packager.